# Dual Booting: How do I share my files and folder between Operating Systems?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-10-preview

I have recently dual booted my computer with Windows 8 and Windows 10 Technical Preview and I would like to share my schoolwork between the Operating Systems. I don't really feel like e-mailing my whole school file system to the other operating system so It would be really handy if there was a way I could make like a shared folder or something. Kindof like a breifcase except not between two different computers.
Any luck?
Thanks

UPDATE: I was able to create a new partiton on my hard drive from which I then accessed from both OS
using the 'This PC' option under File Explorer. I didn't think of this because the 
'This PC' option menu was not currently pulled down. I have moved my School filesystem successfully.
Thanks SadBunny and Nelson Chan for all your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest ways would be things like a large USB stick or an external hard drive or something, or an online cloud storage thing (googledrive?)

If you want to keep it internal, the cleanest and safest way would probably be to add another partition on your harddisk (or add another internal harddisk) in plain old NTFS, that both OS's have access to. That way you don't have to touch one OS partition from another, which is never a good idea.

As far as I know, Windows 10 uses the ReFS filesystem, which cannot be read by Windows 8 (at least not by non-server versions), so the only other option would be to just store all your stuff on your Windows 8 partition and then access it from your Windows 10 sessions.

Comment: Just note that if your two OSes are using only a single partition, resizing them to create a shared partition can be tricky.  USB or plugging in another drive are both much safer and faster.

Comment: Very true. Though what's best also depends on how much data you'd like to share. If it's, like, full DVD's then USB and/or external hard drives are probably too small or too slow or both.
My course of action would be to plop another internal hard drive in the box, they are relatively very cheap nowadays anyway. Even better, install a 128 or 256 GB SSD for the OS's and have a (couple of) big disk(s) for storage, documents, backups etc., and two big disks for physical backups, one stored at home and one at your mother's :)